# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest is consistently very slow. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a brand new Lenovo Yoga laptop, with Windows 10 Pro.

I noticed that Chocolatey seemed really, really slow at downloading and installing software that should install quickly.

This led me to suspect a problem with Powershell, either in PS itself or something about this laptop, and I am having trouble troubleshooting it.

In short `curl` / `Invoke-WebRequest` consistently takes about 43 seconds.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Measure-Command { curl https://microsoft.com }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 43
Milliseconds      : 316
Ticks             : 433164486
TotalDays         : 0.000501347784722222
TotalHours        : 0.0120323468333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.72194081
TotalSeconds      : 43.3164486
TotalMilliseconds : 43316.4486
```

After running it a few times in a row, it'll start running quickly... few hundred milliseconds or so. Then, if I wait a bit, it'll go back to taking 43 seconds. I thought it might be Antivirus related, so I temporarily disabled antivirus, but that had no effect.

I tried curl in Ubuntu in WSL, and didn't see this behavior:

```
marc@ulysses:marc$ time curl https://microsoft.com
<!--TOOLBAR_EXEMPT-->

real    0m0.738s
user    0m0.141s
sys     0m0.234s
```

Any advice on troubleshooting / resolving this? I'm coming back to Windows after many years away and am not even sure where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proxy/antivirus inspecting and caching the response?

Comment: i highly doubt this is a flaw\bug in powershell, probably av software messing with you

Comment: I agree with the other comments, this is likely something scanning your network traffic. Anecdotally, I've seen A/V and other "security" software still cause network problems after being supposedly "disabled". Often they do this through a low-level network driver that they probably can't (or didn't put in the effort to) disable via quick toggle. In my experience, only uninstalling the software reveals that it was the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I uninstalled antivirus, restarted, and still see this behavior. Agree that it's not a PS problem, just not sure how else to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

No idea why this worked, and no idea why it was consistently 43 seconds, but on a whim I disabled IPv6 and that fixed it.‍♀️

Comment: Figured it out. Ultimately it was related to IPv6 settings on my home PC, which the router was using, that effectively broke IPv6 on my network. I wrote about the problem and resolution at https://marcesher.com/2018/01/15/windows-ipv6-slow-or-broken-resolved/

Answer (score 1):

As some have mentioned, this seems to be a local issue, you could try this on other systems in your netwerk to see whether it is your ISP, a proxy or something else network related, updates or a newer powershell version might help but i guess you are already on 5.0 ;)

```
cls
$Results = @{
    "InvokeWeb" = @()
    "curl" = @()
}

1..4 | Foreach  {
    $Results["InvokeWeb"] += Measure-Command {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://microsoft.com"}
    $Results["curl"] += Measure-Command {curl "https://microsoft.com"}
}
```

Output:

```
$Results

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                 
InvokeWeb                      {00:00:00.6267722, 00:00:00.6085871, 00:00:00.6476704, 00:00:00.6381885}                                                                              
curl                           {00:00:00.6342388, 00:00:00.6240474, 00:00:00.6083872, 00:00:00.6594317}
```

The first request can be 3 times slower e.g 1 second other request will benefit of caching.

Comment: This is slick. And it showed me something. Typical output looks like this:

Name                           Value

----                           -----
InvokeWeb                      {00:00:44.2034475, 00:00:00.9393922, 00:00:01.0989707, 00:00:00.9324853}
curl                           {00:00:00.8192917, 00:00:01.0490964, 00:00:00.8661937, 00:00:00.9652688}

BUT... when I switched off of my wifi and onto my mobile hotspot, the slow behavior went away. I can't for the life of me figure out why that would happen though

Comment: Outside of your IPv6 choke point, the PoSH web cmdlets in PoSHv5x and below are just slow as well. That has been corrected in PSCode (PowerShell v6). The was a recent talk by one of the Devs working on the web cmdlets that covered the performance improvements. You can watch the talk here: PowerShell Core Web Cmdlets in Depth   https://www.freeconferencecall.com/wall/recorded_audio?audioRecordingUrl=https%3A%2F%2Frs0000.freeconferencecall.com%2Fstorage%2FsgetFCC2%2FHjHcm%2FDw1lT&subscriptionId=2918574

Answer (score 1):

Possible ways to fix a slow Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell:

- Add `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` to your code.
- Use DownloadFile instead of Invoke-WebRequest if possible:

  ```
      $wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
      $wc.DownloadFile($url, $localFile)
  ```
- Turn off IPV6 "automatic configuration" features, or turn off IPV6 entirely, in the network settings of the computer that is running the Powershell script. The procedure to do this will be different depending on which operating system that the computer is running.

The last one, turning off IPV6, was the one that fixed the problem for me personally. Invoke-WebRequest only behaved slowly when I was connected to a friend's internet connection in their apartment, and their network router had something bad in its IPV6 auto-configuration settings.