# How to install an .msi program in Azure Pipeline (Windows)

Tags: azure-pipelines, cppcheck

My objective is to install CppCheck in a Microsoft-Hosted image in Azure Pipelines.
I already did this for an Ubuntu image, but CppCheck for Ubuntu is outdated. My pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- job: MisraCheck
  displayName: Check for Misra Compliance

  steps:

  - script: |
      sudo apt-get install cppcheck
    displayName: 'Install cppcheck'

  - script: |
      cppcheck --error-exitcode=1 --addon=misra.json .
    displayName: 'Run cppcheck'
```

As I am familiar with Linux (and apt-get), it was very easy to set-up this pipeline. But now I have to "translate" this pipeline to use on a Windows image.

CppCheck for Windows is a downloadable .msi file available at [this](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/) page. The download link is easy to get.

I am aware that I need to use a Windows image in the pipeline, like "windows-2019" or "vs2017-win2016". The main question is how can I replace the apt-get command to get the .msi file from a link and install it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to install an .msi program in Azure Pipeline (Windows)

You could use the Powershell task to install the .msi file:

```
Start-Process $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cppcheck-2.6-x64-Setup.msi -ArgumentList "/quiet"

Start-Sleep 180 #waiting for installing complete
```

And you need upload the `.msi` to your repo. Or you could use PowerShell scripts to download the `.msi` from the URL：

**Update:**

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/releases/download/2.6/cppcheck-2.6-x64-Setup.msi -OutFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cppcheck-2.6-x64-Setup.msi

Start-Sleep 90 #waiting for downloadig complete
```

[image]

Comment: "Or you could use PowerShell scripts to download the .msi from the URL" Can you please provide more info?

Comment: Both the download and install commands are working. Thanks for the help! The only part left is to run cppcheck (the cppcheck executable isn't being found). I'll post the final solution once its working.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this? The command below gives me the error "cppcheck is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
- script: |
      set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\

      cppcheck --error-exitcode=1 --addon=misra.json --inline-suppr .

    displayName: 'MISRA Check'

Comment: @RafaelNicolay, There is no such document. This is a basic skill as a developer. This new error is obviously that Cppcheck is not added to the system path. You only need to google how to add a file path to the system path.

Answer (score 2):

Posting the final solution. This pipeline is a "translation" for the one I posted when opened the question.

```
# This pipeline uses a Windows image as host to install cppcheck to verify MISRA guidelines.

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

jobs:
- job: MisraCheck
  displayName: Check for Misra Compliance

  steps:

# Download and Install CppCheck(full install since we need the MISRA plugin)
  - powershell: |
      Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/releases/download/2.6/cppcheck-2.6-x64-Setup.msi -OutFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cppcheck-2.6-x64-Setup.msi
      Start-Process $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cppcheck-2.6-x64-Setup.msi -ArgumentList "/quiet ADDLOCAL=CppcheckCore,CLI,Translations,ConfigFiles,PlatformFiles,PythonAddons,CRT" -Wait
    displayName: 'Download and Install Cppcheck'

# Adds Cppcheck to PATH and runs it
  - script: |
      PATH=C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\;%PATH%
      cppcheck --error-exitcode=1 --addon=misra.json --inline-suppr .
    displayName: 'MISRA Check'
```

PS: This isn't a good solution because it takes several minutes to finish the pipeline. While the Ubuntu pipeline takes about 30 seconds to complete, the Windows one can take up to 4 minutes. Maybe the correct thing to do is build an agent for this.

Thanks to Leo Liu-MSFT for the help!

Comment: I bet it's the download on windows that is your issue - `Invoke-Webrequest` is extremely slow. If you're running this on a windows agent, look up `Start-BITSTransfer`

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268279/powershell-invoke-webrequest-is-consistently-very-slow-how-can-i-fix-this